# How to select data from 'Stripe Object' in django as in models?

Tags: python, django, pinax

I am developing a django application using Pinax-Stripe. In my models there is this code:

```
class Plan(StripeObject):
    amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=9)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    interval = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    interval_count = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    statement_descriptor = models.TextField(blank=True)
    trial_period_days = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    def __str__(self):
         return  "{} ({}{})".format(self.name,            CURRENCY_SYMBOLS.get(self.currency, ""), self.amount)
```

Now you know that in models, we can select data using `Model.objects.get(id=pk)`

But when i use the same in this `'StripeObject'` it gives me undefined error. Does anyone know how to select data from this `'Stripe Object'` model thing?

Here is my code for views.py:

```
class SubscriptionCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PaymentsContextMixin, CustomerMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "pinax/stripe_b/subscription_create.html"
    form_class = PlanForm

    def set_customer(self):
        if self.customer is None:
            self._customer = customers.create(self.request.user)

    def subscribe(self, customer, plan, token):
        subscriptions.create(customer, plan, token=token)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.set_customer()
        try:
            self.subscribe(self.customer, plan=form.cleaned_data["plan"], token=self.request.POST.get("stripeToken"))
            #added code starts here
            current_user = self.request.user           
            user_space = Space.objects.get(user = current_user)
            user_space.available_harddrive = 1024
            user_space.available_ram = 1024
            user_space.save()
            plan=form.cleaned_data["plan"]
            plan_pk = Plan.get(id = plan.pk)

            #added code ends here    
            return redirect("pinax_stripe_subscription_list")
        except stripe.StripeError as e:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form, errors=smart_str(e)))
```

And this is where i get the problem:

```
 plan=form.cleaned_data["plan"] 
 plan_pk = Plan.get(id = plan.pk)
```

Comment: why dont you try `plan_pk = Plan.objects.get(id = plan.pk)`

Comment: I tried, it doesnt work

Comment: please paste your error traceback

Comment: There is no primary key defined for the Plan object. Try using the stripe_id field instead.

Comment: Also not sure what you are trying to do as the get would return an object, not the key, maybe the variable is named wrong.